# How do I determine exactly what is causing this Ember deprecation?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth, deprecation-warning

Below is a screenshot of an Ember deprecation. It's from a brand new Ember 2.3.0 app with `Ember Simple Auth` installed. I believe the depreciation comes from either Ember Simple Auth, or one of its dependencies because it's not there before installing this addon.

The depreciation is about using `this.container` instead of `getOwner(this)`, and was introduced in Ember 2.3.0. I've looked inside Ember Simple Auth and found a few instances of this. However, if I just fix them inside `node_modules`, it doesn't get rid of the console log message (even if I restart the server manually).

I can see that the code in the Sources tab changes when I change the files inside `node_modules`, so I'm not changing the wrong files like a crazy person. This leads me to believe that it must also be in one of Ember Simple Auth's dependencies.

The deprecation doesn't show up in Ember Inspector for some reason, so I can't just click the link to go to the source. I've tried hitting reload inside Ember Inspector just in case, but that's changed nothing.

I really want to track this down so I can get rid of the warning, and submit some pull requests to these projects.

What should I do to determine exactly what is causing this warning?

[image]

Comment: This is a fairly [recent deprecation](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/15/ember-2-3-released.html#toc_introducing-owners-and-deprecating-containers), the owner api hasn't been documented yet, I wouldn't worry about it that much

Comment: I'm aware of how recent it is, and I'm not actually worried as such, it's just a deprecation, not an error. I just wanted to help. Anyway, I took Kate's advice and found it was actually in Ember Simple Auth itself, but there are already issues and PRs for it, which is cool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the length of your stack trace to find where the deprecation is being thrown. On load, `Error.stackTraceLimit=1000;`. I usually put it in app.js when debugging.

Comment: This helped. I was able to go back far enough to see where it originated. Thanks!

Comment: This addon I have since created might be useful http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-cli-stack-trace-limit